# Reading the value of the cell

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have some `DataGridView` code written in vb.net.  (Nothing is attached to a `datasource`.)

The 4th column is a `checkboxCell`. How do I detect if that `checkBox` is checked or unchecked?

This code strangely reports TRUE or FALSE at random times.  It even turns *ON* the `checkbox` in rows other than the row I clicked in.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
   Dim whichGrid As DataGridView = CType(sender, DataGridView)

   Dim rowClicked As Int16 = e.RowIndex

   Call MsgBox(rowClicked & vbCrLf & whichGrid.Rows(rowClicked).Cells(4).Value)

End Sub
```

All the other examples I've looked at here (and elsewhere) don't seem to help.  Their solutions are always:

- Just check the cell's VALUE.
- Just learn c#, and learn to convert it to vb.net.
- Just check VALUE for nothing, or null, or "", or all of those.
- Convert VALUE to a bool.
- Attach it to a datasource instead.
- Set TrueValue and FalseValue.

I've tried countless other methods, none seem to actually get the `checkbox` ON/OFF value in vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the cell's value to a Boolean:

```
Dim RowIndex As Integer = ...
Dim ColumnIndex As Integer = ...

Dim IsTicked As Boolean = CBool(DataGridView1.Rows(RowIndex).Cells(ColumnIndex).Value)

If IsTicked Then
    MessageBox.Show("You ticked the box.")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("You cleared the box.")
End If
```